# Confluence session destroyed event

Tags: confluence

is there any way in confluence 5.5.1 to get an event when a session is destroyed? 
a) I have a class that implements the HttpSessionListener, InitializingBean, DisposableBean but still nothing.
b) The logoutevent is not fired when servlet is destroyed, although in documentation is stated otherwise.
c) The SessionDestroyedEvent is throwing a class not found error.

Do i miss something?

Comment: You have imported this package perhaps? org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionDestroyedEvent

Comment: No, that's not. Solution was to import the SessionDestroyedEvent object not directly from spring but from confluence itself using package com.atlassian.sal.api.events.SessionDestroyedEvent